# Calculate proper number of elements in a sample

Tags: sampling, sample-size, small-sample

Suppose that I own several convenience stores across the U.S. and I want to infer the share of market for different brands by just analyzing their sell behavior in my stores (ex. I might infer that Coca-cola, pepsi and bigcola have a share of market of 56%, 40% and 4% respectively because I register 1 million dollars in soda sales and 56% of that belongs to Coca-cola). However I have few stores in specific locations (let's say 4 stores in Houston) and those stores register low sell volumes of some products (ex. in 1 Houston store I have low volume sales of Big Cola). Is there a way of calculating a minimum amount of stores so I can calculate the share of market for a specific brand in a specific location without knowing the total population? (ex. I don't know how many convenience stores in Houston, I only have data from my 4 stores) I considered the following formula but in this case I require the population

$$
\frac{\frac{z^2 \times p(1-p)} {e^2} } {1+ \frac{z^2 \times p(1-p)} {e^2 N} }
$$
Where $N=$ population size, $z=$ z-score (1.96), $p=$ 50%, and $e=$margin of error (ex. 5%). However I don't have the population size.

Also if this is not possible, could you recommend me a method to maybe have an estimate of share of market given that little data?
I would appreciate any insight that you could give me.

Comment: I have had to address exactly this problem on a far larger scale in a different US market.  (I had years of daily data about all *individual transactions* in almost half the outlets in this market.) In my case the most significant issue was the fact that the data did not constitute a random sample of the outlets.  You likely have the same issue.  Until you deal with it, no statistical formula will give a valid answer to your question.  BTW, it's easy to find the total population: the US Census provides information down to extremely detailed geographic levels (the Census Block).

Comment: Thanks a lot @whuber. So even if I have a lot of stores but they have low volume sales of a specific brand there is no way to tackle the problem, am I correct?

Comment: There are ways, but they require more sophisticated models and additional data.  In my case I was able to obtain information about store locations, sizes, demographics, etc. for every single store in the market.  That enabled me to estimate the sales at the stores not in the sample.  (As it turned out, those estimated sales were about 30% lower on average than at stores in the sample, indicating the likely magnitude of the sample bias.)  Getting this information about the entire population was key.